# How to avoid widening of plot illustration when using plotly instead of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm plotting a bubble map in R Shiny which displays the sales volume of different city locations (called 'Stadt' in the data) in Germany. Therefore, I basically use a German default map (.rds) and complement it with plot layers of the bubbles.
Instead of ggplot I would like to use plotly, since it has more default features which are very useful for arranging the displayed information on the map.
However, when I apply the plotly function, the plot shows a very widely deformed country shape. The bubbles and the map legend displayed on the side work fine.

- Here is the ggplot with the correct shape: https://ibb.co/dL4HTRG
- Here is the deformed output of plotly: https://ibb.co/bWR2XP2

I'm aware that it is possible to fix height and size by the corresponding commands inside the ggplot brackets, but this does not lead to the required result in this case.
The map should adapt to the window size with maintaining its correct width-to-height ratio.
Is there another possibility to solve this except of fixing manually size and width by trial and error?

The basic code looks like the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
##pool package necessary for dbpool function in order to access database via function in 'database_init.R'
library(pool)

### load and preprocess the German geo map polygons. Download here http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/DEU_adm1.rds 
map_data_sp2 <- readRDS("gadm36_DEU_2_sp.rds")
map_data_1 <- fortify(map_data_sp2, region = "NAME_1")

# link to database and declaration as 'pool'
  pool <- dbPool(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = "rlyshiny_",
    host = "85.214.74.4",
    username = "xxxxxxxx",
    password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarPanel()
  ),
  dashboardBody(
  plotlyOutput("heatmap")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heatmap <- renderPlotly({

    locations <- dbReadTable(pool,"Locations")

  ##tbl extrahiert salesdata aus pool
    sales_data <- pool%>%
      tbl("Salesdata")%>%
      as.data.frame()%>%
      merge(locations, by="Stadt")%>%
      select(Material,Nettogewicht,Stadt,Longitude,Latitude)%>%
      group_by(Material,Stadt,Longitude,Latitude)%>%
      summarise(Nettogewicht=sum(Nettogewicht))

    ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=map_data_1,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),fill="grey",color="white")+
      geom_point(data=sales_data,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude, size=Nettogewicht,colour=Stadt),alpha=0.7)+
      scale_size(range = c(2,20))+
      theme_void() + 
      coord_map()    
  }

  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```